# NestJS TypeORM: if synchronize: true and tables exists, SQL Error

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

When I run `npm run start` with both synchronize and auto load enabled in TypeORM, if a table has already been created in the previous `npm run start`, the following `QueryFailedError` is returned.
I have no choice but to delete all tables before `npm run start`.
How can I enable `npm run start` with synchronize and auto load enabled whether the schema of the table is updated or not?

```
error: Error: text type with an unknown/unsupported collation cannot be hashed
    at Packet.asError (/Users/myname/Documents/works/ski-backend/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
    at Query.execute (/Users/myname/Documents/works/ski-backend/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
    at PoolConnection.handlePacket (/Users/myname/Documents/works/ski-backend/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/Users/myname/Documents/works/ski-backend/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/Users/myname/Documents/works/ski-backend/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/myname/Documents/works/ski-backend/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:360:25)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) {
  code: 'ER_INTERNAL_ERROR',
  errno: 1815,
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  sqlMessage: 'text type with an unknown/unsupported collation cannot be hashed',
  sql: "SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'staging-myservice' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'user' UNION SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'staging-myservice' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'car'"
}
```

app.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      url: 'mysql://<username>:<password>@<host>/<database>?ssl={"rejectUnauthorized":true}',
      synchronize: true,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      logging: true,
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
      },
    }),
  ]
})
```

user.entity.ts

```js
import { Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Entity } from 'typeorm';
import { Field, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @Field()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @Field()
  name: string;
}
```

car.entity.ts

```js
import { Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Entity } from 'typeorm';
import { Field, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class Car {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @Field()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @Field()
  name: string;
}
```

What I tried

1. Specify the table name explicitly. `@Entity({ name: 'user' })`
2. Specify public schame. `@Entity({ name: 'user', schema: 'public' })`
3. Explicitly disable migrationsRun. `migrationsRun: false`
4. Remove `dist/` directory.
5. Install `mysql` module instead of `mysql2`

Answer (score 3):

```
synchronize - Indicates if database schema should be auto-created on every application launch. 
Be careful with this option and don't use this in production - otherwise, you can lose production data. 
This option is useful during debugging and development. As an alternative to it, you can use CLI and run schema:sync command. 
Note that for MongoDB database it does not create a schema, because MongoDB is schemaless. Instead, it syncs just by creating indices.
```

This is the expected behavior for `synchronise`, as per TypeORM [docs](https://typeorm.io/data-source-options).

I think the best alternative for you is to not use it at all. Or configure it via some environment variable.